# Rest operator with Variable reference

Tags: javascript

I can't understand why these two codes don't work the same:

```
function sum(...array) {
return array.reduce((total, element) => {
    return total += element;
})};

let total = sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
console.log(total);
```

This one works as expected and returns the sum of ...array (10)

But when I try to do the same by calling the function with a variable reference:

```
function sum(...array) {
return array.reduce((total, element) => {
    return total += element;
})
}

let myValues = (1, 2, 3, 4)

let total = sum(myValues);
console.log(total)
```

The output is 4.
Why the function works differently in the two situations?

Comment: `console.log(myValues)` you'll see it is `4`, because this: `(1, 2, 3, 4)` is not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parenthesis are expressions that JS evaluates. Similar to how:

```
let a = (1 + 2) // a = 3 

let b = (10 || 5) + 1 // b = 11. 10 is truthy so (10 || 5) evaluates to 10

let c = (null || 6) + 1 // c = 7. (null || 6) evaluates to 6
```

In this case, `(1,2,3,4)` evaluates to `4`. If you want to use variables, you can add the numbers to an array and spread `...` that array when calling the function:

```js
function sum(...array) {
return array.reduce((total, element) => {
    return total += element;
})
}

let myValues = [1, 2, 3, 4]

let total = sum(...myValues);
console.log(total) // 10
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second example `array` looks like this: `[4]` instead of `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

There are not tuples in JavaScript, you can't wrap items with `()` you have to use `[]`.

Also, your function expect each item separately, so you should spread first

```
const myValues = [1, 2, 3, 4]
sum(...myValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

when you write

`let total = sum(1, 2, 3, 4)`

this means that you are passing 4 arguments to function so it will pass 4 values and `sum it to 10`. but in your code,

`let myValues = (1, 2, 3, 4)`

you have redefined myValues four times to 4 only so when the final function will execute it will just have one value 4 for sum . so the final `output is 4`.